# Possible to access AndroidViewModel of Activity via Fragment?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-architecture-components

In the summer of last year I started refactoring my Android application with Android's architecture components (Room, ViewModel, LiveData).

I have two Room repositories, one of them is accessed by multiple views (fragments) of the application. Because of that I used an `AndroidViewModel`, which has access to this repository and which is initialized in my `MainActivity`.

```java
new ViewModelProvider(this).get(CanteensViewModel.class);
```

In my two fragments I accessed this ViewModel by

```java
new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(CanteensViewModel.class);
```

Until yesterday that worked perfectly. But then I updated my dependencies and since `androidx.lifecycle` version 2.2.0 this does not work anymore. I always get an exception (siehe EDIT 2):

```java
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.(...).CanteensViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
```

So I checked the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider) and as I understood right I should/could now use

```java
ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication()).create(CanteensViewModel.class);
```

to get my ViewModel. But with this approach I can't add the `owner` (parameter of `ViewModelProvider`s constructor), which results in the problem, that I can't really access the ViewModel I created in the Activity from inside my fragments.

Is there a way I can access the Activity's ViewModel from inside the fragments? Or would it be better to *recreate* the ViewModel in each fragment by

```java
ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getActivity().getApplication()).create(CanteensViewModel.class);
```

instead of creating it inside the Activity?

**EDIT:**
It seems to work, when I use the other [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider) of `ViewModelProvider`, where a `AndroidViewModelFactory` is the second parameter.

```java
new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(CanteensViewModel.class);
```

Doing this in my `MainActivity` I can access the `CanteensViewModel` in my `Fragment` via

```java
new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(CanteensViewModel.class);
```

**EDIT 2**
Stacktrace for above mentioned exception:

````java
2020-02-28 14:30:16.098 25279-25279/com.pasta.mensadd E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.pasta.mensadd, PID: 25279
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pasta.mensadd/com.pasta.mensadd.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.pasta.mensadd.ui.viewmodel.CanteensViewModel
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2795)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2873)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1602)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6543)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.pasta.mensadd.ui.viewmodel.CanteensViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:221)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at com.pasta.mensadd.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2748)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2873) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1602) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6543) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.pasta.mensadd.ui.viewmodel.CanteensViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
        at com.pasta.mensadd.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2748) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2873) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1602) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6543) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
    ```
````

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> So I checked the docs and as I understood right I should now use
>
> ```
> ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(
>      this.getApplication()).create(CanteensViewModel.class);
> ```

Please share a link to this "docs" you mentioned, because this is NOT the first time I see this code, and yet it was equally wrong in both cases.

The code you actually should be using is

```
new ViewModelProvider(this).get(CanteensViewModel.class);
```

> Is there a way I can access the Activity's ViewModel from inside the fragments? Or would it be better to recreate the ViewModel in each fragment by

```
new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(CanteensViewModel.class);
```

Consider [also receiving a `SavedStateHandle` as an argument in your `AndroidViewModel`, and not only `Application`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/lifecycle/lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/SavedStateViewModelFactory.java#114).

---

If you ask me, apparently the removal of `ViewModelProviders.of()` was an API mistake, but this is what we have now.

---

---

---

**EDIT:** With the help of the provided stack trace, I can finally somewhat figure out what's going on.

> ```
>     at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)
> ```

We are using `NewInstanceFactory` as the default. What does default `NewInstanceFactory` do? [It just calls no-arg constructor](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/lifecycle/lifecycle-viewmodel/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.java#219) if available.

Wait, what? Isn't it supposed to fill in the `Application` for an `AndroidViewModel`?

Theoretically yes, as long as you got the original default `ViewModelProvider.Factory`, but this is not the one!

Why is it not the one that can fill in AndroidViewModel?

See [this commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/893865b74f6a7182bd4ff423783a1924651aa9b4)

> ```
> Add default ViewModel Factory interface
>
> Use a marker interface to allow instances of
> ViewModelStoreOwner, such as ComponentActivity
> and Fragment, to provide a default
> ViewModelProvider.Factory that can be used with
> a new, concise ViewModelProvider constructor.
>
> This updates ComponentActivity and Fragment to
> use that new API to provide an
> AndroidViewModelFactory by default. It updates
> the 'by viewModels' Kotlin extensions to use
> this default Factory if one isn't explicitly
> provided.
> ```

Also

> ```
> ComponentActivity:
>
> +    @NonNull
> +    @Override
> +    public ViewModelProvider.Factory getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory() {
> +        if (getApplication() == null) {
> +            throw new IllegalStateException("Your activity is not yet attached to the "
> +                    + "Application instance. You can't request ViewModel before onCreate call.");
> +        }
> +        return ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getApplication());
> +    }
> +
> ```

And most importantly

> ```
> public ViewModelProvider(@NonNull ViewModelStoreOwner owner) {
>     this(owner.getViewModelStore(), owner instanceof HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory
>             ? ((HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory) owner).getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory()
>             : NewInstanceFactory.getInstance());
> }
> ```

This means that you get the default view model provider factory that can properly set up AndroidViewModel **if** the ViewModelStoreOwner implements `HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory`.

Theoretically, `ComponentActivity` is indeed a `HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory`; and `AppCompatActivity` extends from `ComponentActivity`.

In your case however, that doesn't seem to be the case. For some reason, your `AppCompatActivity` is not `HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory`.

I think the solution to your problem is to update Lifecycle to 2.2.0, and ALSO update `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx` to **at least** 1.2.0. (specifically at least AndroidX-Activity 1.1.0, and AndroidX-Fragment 1.2.0).

Comment: Thanks four your answer! I will add the link to the documentation in a second.
As I already said, I already tried your proposal `new ViewModelProvider(this).get(CanteensViewModel.class);`, but then I get the `java.lang.InstantiationException` I also posted.

Comment: That is very interesting, if you don't provide a factory to the ViewModelProvider, it should automatically choose the default factory, but you can try passing in a `SavedStateViewModelFactory` yourself. AFAIK the new default factory os `SavedStateViewModelFactory`, and it should instantiate AndroidViewModel correctly. I would need a COMPLETE stack trace to know where the ViewModel instantiation fails with the default factory you used. Maybe the issue is that AndroidViewModels require `(Application, SavedStateHandle)` as their default constructor arguments now.

Comment: I added the complete stack trace. I tried adding an AndroidViewModelFactory as second parameter, then it works (see EDIT 1).

Comment: You have a very interesting problem, I'll edit my answer soon.

Comment: Thank you very much for your research and your answer! I will try that on monday, when I am back at work. Until now I did not even have the `androidx.core`, `androidx.activity` and `androidx.fragment` dependencies in my gradle file. Only `androidx.appcompat`, from which I am getting the `AppCompatActivity`. My fragments extend from `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`.
I think I have to update/enhance my androidx knowledge :o

Comment: It worked! I added `androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.2` and `androidx.core:core:1.2.0` to my dependencies. ;)

Comment: If the answer helped, you should accept it with the tick mark ;) happy to hear it worked out

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this thread while searching for a similar problem, but in my case I was simply trying to get an instance of `AndroidViewModel` from my activity. I was presented with the same same zero constructor error. Adding `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"` solved the issue for me even though I'm not using any fragments in my app.