# AndroidViewModel instantiated without passing application context?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I am currently digging through the `Android Room with a View` sample app, full source code available [here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/tree/kotlin). In this project, an [`WordViewModel`](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/blob/kotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample/WordViewModel.kt) of type `AndroidViewModel` is defined:

```
class WordViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application)
```

Note how the constructor requires an `Application` instance to be passed in.
Yet when I check the [`MainActivity`](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/blob/kotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample/MainActivity.kt), the `WordViewModel` is retrieved without passing in the 
`Application` instance:

```
// Get a new or existing ViewModel from the ViewModelProvider.
mWordViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(WordViewModel.class);
```

How is that possible, how can the `WordViewModel` be retrieved without passing in the `Application` instance and without using a custom factory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AndroidX-Activity 1.2.0's `ComponentActivity` (and therefore `AppCompatActivity`) implements `HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory`, which returns an `ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getApplication())` from your Activity/Fragment by default, allowing you to get the application from this `AndroidViewModelFactory` without you having to explicitly pass it.

Then, this factory instantiates your ViewModel via reflection using a `__(application)` constructor.

It's generally a better idea to use `SavedStateViewModelFactory` in order to be able to receive a `SavedStateHandle` in a similar manner (`___(application, savedStateHandle)`) though.

So to fix the problem, you need to add up-to-date versions of `core-ktx`, `activity-ktx` and `fragment-ktx` explicitly in your code.

Comment: See similar question with more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60451554/2413303

Comment: could you also have a look at a similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61063844/androidviewmodel-with-savedstate ?

Answer (score 4):

Dependencies

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"

implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.4"
```

Application Class

```
class App : Application() {
    //Code
}
```

AndroidViewModel Class

```
class TestVM (app : android.app.Application) : AndroidViewModel(app){
    // Cast app to the application class
    val myApplication : App = app as App
}
```

In Fragment

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(TestVM::class.java)
}
```

Comment: Here I'm not passing context to view model. this means ViewModelStoreOwner.  public ViewModelProvider(@NonNull ViewModelStoreOwner owner) { ... }. So why downgrade the answer @IgorGanapolsky

Comment: Mysterious. Rollbacked.