# AndroidViewModel with SavedState

Tags: android, factory, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I need to use an `AndroidViewModel` with application context and a `SavedStateHandle`. I have it already working with application context, but I fail adding a `SavedStateHandle` to it.

This is what I have, with only the application context:

```
// A1. get ViewModel in Fragment
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(viewLifecycleOwner).get(MyViewModel::class.java)

// A2. MyViewModel derives from my custom BaseAndroidViewModel
class MyViewModel(application: Application) :BaseAndroidViewModel(application)

// A3. BaseAndroidViewModel in turn derives from AndroidViewModel
open class BaseAndroidViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application)
```

I assume for this question this could likely be reduced to:

```
// B1. get ViewModel in Fragment
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(viewLifecycleOwner).get(MyViewModel::class.java)

// B2. BaseAndroidViewModel in turn derives from AndroidViewModel
class MyViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application)
```

So, for also having a `SavedStateHandle` in `MyViewModel`, how would I have to modify the call in the fragment (line `B1` in the example code) ? Do I need an explicit call to the factory `SavedStateViewModelFactory`? How exactly would that look like? (I am still new to Kotlin/Android, I've never worked with a factory before)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:** in the final release of `AndroidX-Activity 1.2.0` and `AndroidX-Fragment 1.1.0`, they made `SavedStateViewModelFactory` the default factory in AppCompatActivity/Fragment, so it is not needed to override the default factory (which is what the second half of this answer does.)

Updating and then using

```
class MyViewModel(val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): ViewModel()

class MyAndroidViewModel(application: Application, val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): AndroidViewModel(application)
```

Should just work.

---

**ORIGINAL:**

> how would I have to modify the call in the fragment (line B1 in the example code) ? Do I need an explicit call to the factory SavedStateViewModelFactory? How exactly would that look like?

In AndroidX-Activity 1.2.0, they added a new method called `getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory()`:

> ```
> +    @NonNull
> +    @Override
> +    public ViewModelProvider.Factory getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory() {
> +        if (getApplication() == null) {
> +            throw new IllegalStateException("Your activity is not yet attached to the "
> +                    + "Application instance. You can't request ViewModel before onCreate call.");
> +        }
> +        return ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getApplication());
> +    }
> +
> ```

Which means if I have a `BaseActivity` or a `BaseFragment`, I can swap this out for the `SavedStateViewModelFactory` from `viewmodel-savedstate`:

```
class BaseActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory(): ViewModelProvider.Factory = 
        SavedStateViewModelFactory(application, this, intent?.extras ?: Bundle())
}

class BaseFragment: Fragment() {
    override fun getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory(): ViewModelProvider.Factory = 
        SavedStateViewModelFactory(requireActivity().application, this, arguments ?: Bundle())
}
```

Once you have that, you can rely on the automatic instantiation of ViewModel with `SavedStateHandle` as one of their arguments:

```
class MyViewModel(val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): ViewModel()

class MyAndroidViewModel(application: Application, val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): AndroidViewModel(application)
```

Beware that the order `application, savedStateHandle` is expected by `SavedStateViewModelFactory`.

However, if you do need custom arguments on top of that, then you'd have to provide a `object: AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory` when you invoke the `ViewModelProvider(viewModelStoreOwner).get(...)` method

Comment: thank you for that fast and detailed response :-) There's a slight copy&paste mistake in the override for `getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory` for `BaseFragment`: `application` isn't directly available in the `Fragment`. I think it should be `activity?.application!!`- can you confirm that? Is there a better way? Looks a little bit ugly with all that null handling stuff ;-)

Comment: I added `requireActivity().application` but if this is invoked when Activity is not around, that would be very disappointing. ViewModels should be initialized in `onCreate`, but if Activity were unavailable at that time, you'd have to get the `application` in `onAttach(Context)`... AFAIK the `activity` IS available in `onCreate` though.

Comment: Thank you. I learned something new: the default factory can also pass in the `SavedStateHandle`. So finally I *only* added `SavedStateHandle` as second parameter to my ViewModel. Quote: "When using Fragment 1.2.0 or its transitive dependency Activity 1.1.0, the default factory for ViewModel instances support passing the appropriate SavedStateHandle to your ViewModel without any additional configuration." (source: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate) Guess this also includes what I observed

Comment: Oh, so they've made `SavedStateViewModelFactory` the default? Then you don't even need to override anything. That's great news, I'll update the post. I was not aware of this.

Comment: yeah, seems so. thanks for updating :-) actually my original fault was to try to pass the save state handle up to AndroidViewModel ;-)