# Filter RecyclerView's list with LiveData items with searchview

Tags: android-studio, filter, android-recyclerview, viewmodel, android-livedata

I decided to optimize my code and therefore switch to liveData. I followed a tutorial on youtube ([youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARpn-1FPNE4&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuDihTpkRs6SpZhqgBqPU118)) but I do not quite understand how I can filter my recyclerView when the user enters a word since I do not store any list in my Adapter. I use a simple searchview filter system on my MainActivity.

---

Moreover, I use DiffUtil to update my recyclerView and I update my Adapter thanks to:

```
noteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication()).create(NoteViewModel.class);
noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, adapter::submitList);
```

My code is almost identical to the video but here is a part of it:

ViewModel:

```
public class NoteViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private NoteRepository repository;
    private LiveData<List<Note>> allNotes;

    public NoteViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new NoteRepository(application);
        allNotes = repository.getAllNotes();
    }

    public void insert(Note note) {
        repository.insert(note);
    }

    public void update(Note note) {
        repository.update(note);
    }

    public void delete(List<Note> notes) {
        repository.delete(notes);
    }


    public LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes() {
        return allNotes;
    }
}
```

My repository:

```
public class NoteRepository {

    private NotesDAO notesDAO;
    private LiveData<List<Note>> allNotes;

    public NoteRepository(Application application) {
        NotesDB database = NotesDB.getInstance(application);
        notesDAO = database.notesDAO();
        allNotes = notesDAO.getAllNotes();
    }

    public void insert(Note note) {
        new InsertNoteAsyncTask(notesDAO).execute(note);
    }

    public void update(Note note) {
        new UpdateNoteAsyncTask(notesDAO).execute(note);
    }

    public void delete(List<Note> note) {
        new DeleteNoteAsyncTask(notesDAO).execute(note);
    }


    public LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes() {
        return allNotes;
    }

    private static class InsertNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void> { // SOME STUFF }

    private static class UpdateNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void> { // SOME STUFF }

    private static class DeleteNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<List<Note>, Void, Void> { // SOME STUFF }

}
```

Comment: Note: `new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication()).create(NoteViewModel.class);` please stop doing this, it's wrong. It should be **`new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NoteViewModel.class)`**.

Comment: I tried this but I got an error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class fr.djan.fullrecyclerview.Model.NoteViewModel Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class <en. djan.fullrecyclerview.Model.NoteViewModel> has no zero argument constructor`

Comment: That is caused by a version mismatch in your AndroidX dependencies. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60451458/possible-to-access-androidviewmodel-of-activity-via-fragment/60451554#comment107041221_60451554

Comment: I followed your advice and it works, thank you! (even if that doesn't solve my problem)

Comment: I checked the post but I don't understand how can I modify the `MutableLiveData<String> filterText` when I write something in a searchView thanks to the Transformations.switchMap (sorry i'm a beginner)

Comment: I presume the SearchView has a SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, and you register that listener, you get the new search text from the user, you call `filterText.setValue(newSearchText)` and the switchMap to the dao query will automatically retrieve the new data

Comment: Thanks ! But I have one last issue: when I try to filter my room databse, my method return nothing.. This is my repository method: 

`public LiveData<List<Note>> filter(String input) {
        return notesDAO.filter(input);
}` 

and this is my room query: 

`@Query("SELECT * FROM note_table WHERE LOWER(title) LIKE :search")
LiveData<List<Note>> filter(String search);`

Comment: Try `@Query("SELECT * FROM note_table WHERE LOWER(title) LIKE '%' || :search || '%'") LiveData<List<Note>> filter(String search);`

Answer (score 2):

Finally, thanks to @EpicPandaForce, I did that:

My ViewModel:

```
public class NoteViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private NoteRepository repository;
    private final LiveData<List<Note>> allNotes;
    private MutableLiveData<String> filterText = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public NoteViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new NoteRepository(application);
        allNotes = Transformations.switchMap(filterText, (input) ->
        {
            if(input == null || input.equals(""))
                return repository.getAllNotes();
            else
                return repository.filter(input);
        });
        }

        public void setFilter(String query) {
            filterText.setValue(query);
        }

        public LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes() {
            return allNotes;
        }
}
```

In my repository:

```
public LiveData<List<Note>> filter(String input) {
        try {
            return new FilterNoteAsyncTask(notesDAO).execute(input).get();
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

private static class FilterNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, LiveData<List<Note>>> {
        private NotesDAO notesDAO;

        private FilterNoteAsyncTask(NotesDAO notesDAO) {
            this.notesDAO = notesDAO;
        }

        @Override
        protected LiveData<List<Note>> doInBackground(String... strings) {
            return notesDAO.filter(strings[0]);
        }
    }
```

And I perform the request in the database thanks to:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM note_table WHERE LOWER(title) LIKE '%' || :search || '%'")
LiveData<List<Note>> filter(String search);
```